# How to interpret this Docusaurus error message?

Tags: docusaurus

Not sure what this is... there is no "/test" in the codebase ...

```
Error: Docusaurus server-side rendering could not render static page with path /test because of error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

This only happens when "npm run build", no problems when "npm run start" ...

Comment: maybe there is something related with `/test` in docuasurus.config.js?